# En java quiero hacerle un filtro para buscar algo en especifico dentro de un txt

Tags: java, archivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero hacer un filtro que solo me muestre el codigo  de los articulos que se encuentren en este registro, dejo claro que este registro es dinamico y puede crecer.
por ejemplo :
- los codigos de los articulos son:
12312,1212,222,242324,etc
    lo que no se como consultar en el .txt todos los codigo de articulos que que se encuentren en el algortimo

```
introducir el código aquí
```

```
    introducir el código aquí
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class atletas{
    String dato1="",dato2="",dato3="",dato4="",dato5="",id="";
     Scanner leer = new Scanner (System.in);    
    public void ingresar(){
     System.out.println("=================================");
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;

    try {

        File file = new 
        File("C:\\\\Users\\\\Alexander\\\\Desktop\\\\atleta.txt");
        // Si el archivo no existe, se crea!
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        // flag true, indica adjuntar información al archivo.
        fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        System.out.println("Id del atleta");
        System.out.print(">");id = leer.next();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del atleta");
        System.out.print(">");dato1 = leer.next();
        System.out.println("Ingresa la direccion del atleta");
        System.out.print(">");dato2 = leer.next();
        System.out.println("Ingresa la edad del atleta");
        System.out.print(">"); dato3 = leer.next();
        System.out.println("Ingresa la nacionalidad del atleta");
        System.out.print(">"); dato4 = leer.next();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el sexo del atleta");
        System.out.print(">");dato5 = leer.next();
        bw.write("ID: "+id+"\n");
        bw.write("Nombre: "+dato1+"\n");
        bw.write("Direccion: "+dato2+"\n");
        bw.write("Edad: "+dato3+"\n");
        bw.write("Nacionalidad: "+dato4+"\n");
        bw.write("Sexo: "+dato5+"\n\n");
        System.out.println("información agregada!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bw != null)
                bw.close();
            if (fw != null)
                fw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }        

    }

    public void desnombres(){



    }
    public void desnacionalidad(){


    }

    File fichero = new File 
    ("C:\\\\Users\\\\Alexander\\\\Desktop\\\\atleta.txt");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String respuesta;
    public void participante(){

        try {
    do {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fichero));
        System.out.println("Introduco un nombre que quieras buscar: ");
        respuesta="ID: "+sc.nextLine();


        String linea="";
        boolean encontrado = false;
        while ((linea= br.readLine())!=null) {

            if(linea.equalsIgnoreCase(respuesta)) {
                System.out.println(linea);

                for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
                    System.out.println(br.readLine());
                }   
                encontrado = true;
                break;

            }

        }

        if(!encontrado) System.out.println("El producto no existe");

       System.out.println("============================================");
            System.out.println("¿Quieres introducir otro nombre ingresa si");

            respuesta=sc.nextLine();



    }while(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("si"));
    } catch (IOException ie) {

    System.out.println("Error");
    leer.next();
    }
    }
    }
    public class LB43c {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 0,b = 0,c = 0;
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        atletas obj = new atletas();

    do{
        System.out.println("==========================");
        System.out.println("1- Ingresar Participante");
        System.out.println("2- Desplegar por nombres");
        System.out.println("3- Desplegar Nacionalidad");
        System.out.println("4- Buscar Participante");
        System.out.println("5- Salir");
        System.out.println("==========================");
        try{
        System.out.print(">");a = leer.nextInt();
        switch(a){
        case 1:

        do{
        System.out.println("==========================");
        System.out.println("1- Ingresar datos");
        System.out.println("2- Salir");
        System.out.println("==========================");
        try{
        b= leer.nextInt();
        switch(b){
            case 1:
                obj.ingresar();
                break;
            case 2:break;
            }
        }catch(Exception ei){
            System.out.println("Dato no valido");
            leer.next();
        }

        }while(b!=2);
        break;

        case 2:
        obj.desnombres();
        break;

        case 3:
        obj.desnacionalidad();
        break;

        case 4:

        do{
        System.out.println("==========================");
        System.out.println("1- Consultar participante");
        System.out.println("2- Salir");
        System.out.println("==========================");
        try{
        c= leer.nextInt();
        switch(c){
            case 1:
                obj.participante();
                break;
            case 2:break;
            }
        }catch(Exception eie){
            System.out.println("Participante no encontrado");
            leer.next();
        }

        } while(c!=2);  
        break;

            case 5:break;
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Dato no valido");
            leer.next();
        }

    }while(a!=5);
        System.out.println("Saliste ");
    }  
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido, anteriormente realizaste la misma pregunta, te sugerimos revisar 
 [ask] modifica tu pregunta Agrega el codigo que has tratado o lo que has investigado por favor y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Disculpen es la primera vez que entro aquí y no lei las intrucciones porque este codigo me tiene algo confundido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   /** Muchas gracia bro pero encontre esta que me ayudo
   *Lo que vez en comentario, funciona para ver en que linea encontro las 
   *palabras 
   *que buscaba pero, no use esa funcion porque no lo necesitaba 
   * 
   *Introduje a metodo desnombre y desnacionalidad este codigo, solo le 
   *cambio en texto lo que queria buscar y listo. 
   */
    public void desnombres(){
    Scanner entrada = null;
    String linea;      
    boolean contiene = false;
   //String texto = "Nacionalidad";
    String texto = "Nombre: ";
   // int numeroDeLinea = 1;
    try {
        File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Alexander\\Desktop\\atleta.txt");
        entrada = new Scanner(f);            
        while (entrada.hasNext()) { 
            linea = entrada.nextLine();
            if (linea.contains(texto)) {
                System.out.println(linea);
           //     System.out.println("Linea " + numeroDeLinea + ": "+linea);
                contiene = true;
            }
     //numeroDeLinea++;
        }
        if(!contiene){

            System.out.println(texto + " no se ha encontrado en el archivo");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString() + "No ha seleccionado ningún archivo");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    } finally {
        if (entrada != null) {
            entrada.close();
        }
    } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hice algunos experimentos y creo que tu mejor opción son las expresiones regulares.
Te dejo un código capaz de encontrar el texto según el patrón que indicas. Tú lo podrás acomodar a tus necesidades.

```
package cl.negrolder.lab;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StringFilter {

    private static String sContent = "Codido del articulo 123\\notralinea\\nmaslineas\\nCodido del articulo 456789\\notralineamas";

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        String regex = "Codido del articulo \\d*";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sContent);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Esto te va a escribir en la consola

```
Codido del articulo 123
Codido del articulo 456789
```

Espero te sirva.